# Create custom override for list from mod_articles_categories

Tags: module, overrides, mod-articles-category

I have created custom template override for `mod_articles_categories`,and it works fine.
I also need to create an override for the view ,when we choose a category from the list. 
is it possible?
now the link seems like `index.php?option=com_content&view=category&id=19&Itemid=168`

Comment: cross-posted on `stackoverflow.com`  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35473203/create-custom-override-for-list-from-mod-articles-categories-joomla

Comment: @Joomler IS that a problem?

Answer (score 1):

You have to overwrite com_content's category view. Your overwrite would be located here:

> /templates/<your_template>/html/com_content/category/default.php